# Cannot Send Post Request Jquery $.Post on Internet Explore 9 ActiveX Filtering

Tags: php, jquery

I have a problem with Iexplore 9 ActiveX Filtering.

I create an application which is set session through jquery $.post, when I turn on ActiveX filtering in Iexplore 9, it blocks the post request.

```
$('.sidid').click(function(){
    val = $(this).val();
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) { //when checked
        $.post("session_cetak_po.php", {"sidid":val}, function(results) {
        });
    }else{ //when unchecked
        $.post("session_cetak_po.php", {"sidid":val,"unchecked":"1"}, function(results) {
        });
    }
});
```

Any suggestion how to fix it?

Thanks before :)

Answer (score 0):

Do not turn on ActiveX filtering. :)

Use load() instead of post(). load() send data via GET

Comment: thnks for the suggestion, i'll try :)

Comment: i think `$.load("session_cetak_po.php?sidid="+val , function(results) {  });)`

Comment: hmm get or load is not working (only working if i turn off activeX Filtering :)

Comment: perhaps there is a conflict with one of IE Addon